# Why doesn't join return a string?

Tags: python

```
def group_list(group, users):
  members = group+":"+", ".join(users)
  return members

print(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"]))
```

I get: `Engineering:Kim, Jay, Tom`

but was expecting `'Engineering:Kim, Jay, Tom'`

Comment: That's what it looks like when you print a string.

Comment: Print will  print stings without quotes, to verify that it is returning a string run `type(group_list("Engineering", ["Kim", "Jay", "Tom"]))`

Answer (score 1):

You can just think that:

```
the print function will remove the `'` around the string.
```

just easy to understand, not strictly correct.

Answer (score 1):

`print()` removes the quotes (`''`) from a string because they are not needed. When you print text to the console or screen, the text is always a string, so showing the quotes is redundant and obstructive.

---

To explore this, open your terminal and run `python`, then type:

```
>>> ', '.join(['a','b'])
'a, b'
```

Which does indeed return a string.

Printing will remove the quotes:

```
>>> print(', '.join(['a','b']))
a, b
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print with `'` you can add it like this:

```
def group_list(group, users):
  members = group+":"+", ".join(users)
  return members

print(f"'{group_list('Engineering', ['Kim', 'Jay', 'Tom'])}'")
```